# Using try-catch with a if else loop

Tags: java, arrays, methods, command-line, try-catch

So I am making a program which takes an int input from the command line and then searches the array in the program for the int and if found, return the index of the number. If not, then it throws an exception stating that it wasn't found and end the program. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] intArray = {9, 97, 5, 77, 79, 13, 7, 59, 8, 6, 100, 55, 35, 89, 74, 66, 32, 47, 51, 88, 23};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));

    int intArgs = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    System.out.println("Your entered: " + intArgs);

    FindNum(intArray, intArgs);
}

public static int FindNum(int[] intArray, int intArgs) {
    for (int index = 0; index < intArray.length; index++){
        try{
            if (intArray[index] == (intArgs))
                System.out.println("Found It! = " + index);
            else 
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Element not found in array.");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return -1;      
}
```

While this sort of works and can find the index, it throws the exception for each number in the array instead of just one for the whole array. And if it finds the number in the array, then it replaces one of the lines with the confirmation line from the loop. Example output for 66:

```
[9, 97, 5, 77, 79, 13, 7, 59, 8, 6, 100, 55, 35, 89, 74, 66, 32, 47, 51, 88, 23]
Your entered: 66
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Found It! = 15
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
Element not found in array.
```

How can I make it so that when it finds the number, it only prints the index line and vice versa for the exception. I feel it may have something to do with the loop but not sure what I can do to prevent that.

Comment: Put the loop inside the try-block rather than putting the try- block inside the loop. or better yet, why even have a try-block? Just do the search, and if not found print the error message.

Comment: Put your try-catch outside the for loop, not inside it.

Comment: you are throwing the exception every time to check the value with an element in the array and finds a mismatch, which is incorrect sine you can conclude the element not in array only after you visited all elements.

Comment: Why are you catching the exception if your intention was to throw it out of the function?

Comment: When I try to put the try catch outside the for loop, the code just returns: element not found in array. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @AvenNova read my answer: you shouldn't have a try catch at all. You're supposed to **throw** an exception, not **catch** it.

Comment: @JBNizet When I remove the try catch from the second method and call the method in main, the code doesn't work except for when I enter 9. And then it still throws it exception after the 'Found It! = 0' statement. Also when I try to return the index, it says variable not found.

Comment: Yes, that's also explained in my answer. You should only throw the exception once you **know** you haven't found the element. **After** the loop. Not **inside** the loop. Just think about it: I give you a pile of books. You must find the one titled "Java in a Nutshell". If this book isn't in the pile of books, you must shout. When do you shout? Every time you read the title of a book, or once you've read all the titles and haven't found "Java in a Nutshell"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the code like below..

As per your code, you are checking each element and if not matching, you are throwing an exception. This is not accurate, since you cannot conclude if the element not exist unless you scan all elements. In that case you can use flags to determine if you find a match and after the for loop you can check the flag and throw an exception. Again, if you are planning to catch the exception within the same method, you may not need to throw the exception after all. Instead you can simply return the index or -1 like below..

```
public static int FindNum(int[] intArray, int intArgs) {
   for (int index = 0; index < intArray.length; index++){
        if (intArray[index] == (intArgs)){
            System.out.println("Found It! = " + index);
            return index;
        }
   }
   throw new NoSuchElementException("Element not found in array.");
}
```

Comment: While this works, I have to throw an exception as per the requirements. Thank you for the help though...

Comment: I have updated the answer.. from my previous code, you  just need to replace the `return -1` to a statement to throw the exception..

Comment: This works but it still throws the red exception text. So I used a try catch for when I call the FindNum method in main to only print the text and it works now! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6):

> searches the array in the program for the int and if found, return the index of the number. If not, then it throws an exception stating that it wasn't found and end the program.

Read what you wrote carefully.

If not found, you should throw an exception. You only know you haven't found the value once you have gone through all its elements. So you can't throw from inside the loop. You can only throw after the loop, if you haven't found the element.

Second, you're supposed to throw the exception. You're not doing that: instead, you throw and catch the exception you've just thrown. The point of throwing an exception is to let the caller of the method know that something exceptional happens. You shouldn't throw and catch an exception inside a method.

Finally, your method is supposed to **return** the index. But it doesn't. It always returns -1.

Comment: Thank you! Yours and redflar3's advice helped a bunch, finally got it! I wish I could select two answers instead of one :D

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = -1;
...
    if (intArray[index] == intArgs) i = index;
...
```

Try to make an `int` variable to keep an index of the found element. The last line of the method throws an exception if nothing is found.

```
if (index == -1) throw new NoSuchElementException(...);
```

Another way is returning the index directly and throwing an exception in the end without any conditions.

```
    if (intArray[index] == intArgs) return index;
...
throw new NoSuchElementException(...);
```

I advise you not to return the error code. More natural for Java, in this case, is throwing an unchecked exception.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else and throw statement inside the try. Initialize a variable boolean flag=false. before iteration. If the element is found inside the loop, add condition flag=true and then break from loop. Now after the end of iteration write this : if(!flag) System.out.print("Element not found"); basically you are printing the element not found on every iteration except where the element gets founds which is a terrible error.